# Grammar (at or at the...)

Tags: definite-article

In which of the sentences below would the use of at be grammatically correct?

> i. I do not want to talk about mine stay **at sea**.
>
> or
>
> ii. I do not want to talk about mine stay **at the sea**.

Comment: Your use of ***mine*** to mean ***my*** is archaic / poetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While generally, 'sea' uses an article, in reference to taking a sea voyage, you should not use one.

Examples:

> I am going out to sea.
>
> I recently had a stay at sea.

Examples of places where you should use an article (that is, where it's not referring to a voyage or journey):

> I found him looking at the sea.
>
> I pulled some flotsam up from the sea.

**Side note:** You usually should not use 'mine' unless it's after the noun it's describing. Here's how these sentences are usually structured:

> This is my boat.
>
> This boat is mine.

In very old texts, you might find 'mine' before a word starting with a vowel sound:

> Mine own brother is...
>
> Mine orange is...

But this is considered obsolete, and is now extremely uncommon, so I would avoid it entirely and only use 'mine' after the noun it's describing.